# Looping through an array of nodes and appending a child to each one only appends to the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

I want to loop through an array of nodes referring to SVG elements and append a text element to each one but for some reason all of the text only appears in the last SVG element in the array.

Here's the code

```
var svgs = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');

var moduleNames = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var textEl = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'text');

var i = 1;

while(i < moduleNames.length) {

  textNode = document.createTextNode( moduleNames[i] );
  textEl.appendChild(textNode);
  svgs[i].appendChild(textEl);

  i++;

}
```

Oh, and before I do this I already know the number of SVG elements will be the same length as the moduleNames array.

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably just put var in front of textNode to create a new node each time. You're appending that node, then appending it again, and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> text only appears in the last SVG element

Not in the *last* svg `<text>` element, but in the *only one*. You're creating a single element and keep appending text nodes to it. Appending the same element to different parents doesn't clone it, but only move it.

You probably want to create multiple elements:

```
var moduleNames = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
for (var i=0; i < moduleNames.length; i++) {
    var textEl = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'text'),
        textNode = document.createTextNode( moduleNames[i] );
    textEl.appendChild(textNode);
    svgs[i].appendChild(textEl);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to append a *new* element to each SVG, but you're just moving one across them all, so it ends up on the last one. The easiest way to create new copies of an element is with `cloneNode`

```
svgs[i].appendChild(textEl.cloneNode());
```